# Google app engine: form values added automatically to a model

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine

I'm trying to build up an application with google app engine in python. 
i'm reading this official guide: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/handlingforms
from the example, it seems that i've to do all the data retrieving by hand

```
self.request.get('content')
```

Howevere this solution seems unconvinient, is there any way to map the form to a model (db) and have the form values put directly into this model?

example:

```
class PostOnBlog(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    text = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

now, from this can i automatically create the form? if not ok, i can construct the form by myself.
but, once i've to formcan i've the data automatically mapped to this model when a post is submit? is there any way to do it? or do i've to write all the self.request.get('par_name')?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django on App Engine and be able to use Django's lovely [ModelForms](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms) ( see the **Define Model and Form Classes for our Example** part of the page )

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at wtforms.

http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.appengine

WTForms now includes support for AppEngine fields as well as auto-form generation. You can now map a form to a model directly and also read it back into populate a model once submitted back to your app.